# Рандом в крестиках ноликах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я сделал простую версию игры крестики нолики. При нажатии на ячейку, в ней появляется крестик и вызывается функция, что бы поставить нолик рандомно.

Я добавил условие, что если ячейка не пустая, то ничего не ставить. С крестиком это срабатывает, а вот с ноликом нет. Если ячейка занята то оно ничего вообще не ставит. Как можно нормально это поправить?

```js
$(function() {
  var bot = function() {
    var cell = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
    
    if( $('.board-cell').eq(cell).text() == '' ) $('.board-cell').eq(cell).text( 'O' );
  };

  $('.board-cell').click(function() {
    if( $(this).text() == '' ){
      $(this).text( 'X' );
      bot();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 153px;
  height: 153px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.board-cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="board">
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
$(function() {
  function bot() {
    var $cells = $('.board-cell:empty');
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * $cells.length);
    $cells.eq(i).text( 'O' );
  };

  $('.board-cell').click(function() {
    if( $(this).text() == '' ){
      $(this).text( 'X' );
      bot();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 153px;
  height: 153px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.board-cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="board">
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо :)

Comment: Всё гениально просто

Comment: @Yuri, но не очень эффективно. Впрочем, не хуже, чем в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал, что если найден повтор, то снова запускать функцию `bot` и так до тех пор, пока не будет пустая ячейка. Так же нужно добавить переменную, что бы конце не создалась вечная функция

```js
$(function() {
  var c = 0;
  
  var bot = function() {
    var cell = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1)) + 1;
    
    if( $('.board-cell').eq(cell).text() === '' ){
      $('.board-cell').eq(cell).text( 'O' );
      
      c++;
    }else{
      if(c !== 9){
        bot();
      };
    };
  };

  $('.board-cell').click(function() {
    if( $(this).text() == '' ){
      $(this).text( 'X' );
      
      c++;
      
      bot();
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 153px;
  height: 153px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.board-cell {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="board">
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
  <div class="board-cell"></div>
</div>
```

И я немного ваш рандом переделал, изменив максимальное число на *"9"*

Comment: Спасибо большое :)